# How to get error message from ditto command , when it fails to archive

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unix, terminal

Using ditto command we are archiving folder. When folder contains some files which does not have read permission. It fails to archive. That time ditto command logs error message saying " ditto: "Path" : Permission denied. How to get this error message.

Answer (score 0):

As with any UNIX command, errors are written to `stderr`, which can be captured by adding `2> file` to end of the command:

```
$ ditto src dst 2> error
$ cat error
ditto: /Users/andy/tmp/src/./x: Permission denied
```

If you are running `ditto` from a shell script, then something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/sh
errfile=/tmp/errors.$$
(cd ~/tmp; ditto src dst 2> $errfile)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo There was a problem:
    cat $errfile
else
    echo Everything is cool
fi
```